# How to remove rows from a data frame based on a group condition, without losing some columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe from which I'd like to extract a subset based on a group condition: for a given year x, if a species only counts 1 individual, then remove it from the df.

I am able to have a subset of this kind:

```
df %>%
  group_by(species,year) %>%
  summarise(n_inds = n()) %>%
  filter(n_inds > 1)
```

which gives this results

```
# A tibble: 1,915 x 3
   espece                     year n_inds
   <fct>                     <dbl>  <int>
 1 Agelaioides badius         2003      5
 2 Agelaioides badius         2004      3
 3 Agelaioides badius         2005      4
 4 Amaurospiza moesta         2005      2
 5 Amaurospiza moesta         2014      2
 6 Amblyramphus holosericeus  2006      2
 7 Ammodramus humeralis       2010      4
 8 Ammodramus humeralis       2011      3
 9 Anabacerthia amaurotis     2001      3
10 Anabacerthia amaurotis     2004      5
# ... with 1,905 more rows
```

but it's not totally what I want. This df tells me, for example for the 1st row,  that they are 5 individuals of Agelaioides badius in 2003 that I want to keep in my original df, alongside all the columns with the different measurements for each corresponding bird (I'm working on birds).

If someone has a solution! :)

Thanks a lot

PS: the original df is counting 19501 observations of 9 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need the `summarise` step.  Instead use the logical expression directly in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(species, year) %>%
    filter(n() > 1)
```

---

If we need to create the 'n_inds', then use either `add_count`

```
df %>%
  add_count(species, year) %>%
  filter(n > 1)
```

Or create the column with `mutate`

```
df %>%
  group_by(species, year) %>%
  mutate(ninds = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(ninds > 1)
```

---

When we use `summarise`, it only returns the grouping columns and the summarised column

Comment: I then have a subsequent question: how would you, from this new df, erase all the rows containing the species that appear only one year (and therefore are not seen ever again), no matter this time the number of individuals? For example, I keep "species 1" seen on year x and y but not "species 2" only seen on year z.

Comment: @Recology Perhaps you want `df %>% group_by(species) %>% filter(n_distinct(year) > 1)`

Comment: It seems to work fine! Would you know a simple way to double check if there are no mistakes in the df, regarding what my conditions are? :)

Comment: @Recology  when you say mistakes, are you checking whether all 'species' after the `filter` have only unique 'year'?

Comment: I would like to be 100% sure that every species could be found always on multiple years (>=2 different years). Even if looking at the df it seems to be the case, is there a way to prove it?

Comment: @Recology Once you subset the data you can always check with `df1 <- df %>% group_by(species) %>% filter(n_distinct(year) > 1) %>% ungroup; table(unique(df1[c('species', 'year')]))` or use a logical condition i.e. `df %>% distinct(species, year) %>% count(species, year) %>% transmute(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all`

Comment: @Recology So either of those codes should work.  In the second case, by using `all`, it should return a single TRUE if all have more than one year per species

Comment: ```> df %>% distinct(espece, year) %>% count(espece, year) %>% transmute(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all          [1]FALSE ``` this is what I got, so it's not the expected TRUE?

Comment: @Recology I meant after the `filter`.  sorry, I should have added `df1` instead of `df` i.e. `df1%>% distinct(species, year) %>% count(species, year) %>% transmute(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all`

Comment: sorry I don't get it this time :/

Comment: @Recology  I meant `df1 <- df %>% group_by(species) %>% filter(n_distinct(year) > 1) %>% ungroup` as the filtered data.  Then you are doing the check on 'df1' which is the filtered output.

Comment: oh okay it's clearer thanks a lot, but I still got FALSE as an answer :/

Comment: this is what I have done: ```df1 = df %>% group_by(espece) %>% filter(n_distinct(year) > 1) %>% ungroup

df1 %>% distinct(espece, year) %>% count(espece, year) %>% transmute(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all```

Comment: @Recology  Do you have `NA` elements.  Then use `df1 <- df %>% group_by(species) %>% filter(n_distinct(year, na.rm = TRUE) > 1) %>% ungroup` and use `df1%>% distinct(species, year) %>% na.omit %>% count(species, year) %>% transmute(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all`

Comment: I don't have any NA:  ```sum(is.na(df))   [1] 0```

Comment: @Recology Can you check the output of `df1%>% distinct(species, year) %>% na.omit %>% count(species, year)`

Comment: ```A tibble: 1,865 x 3
   espece                  year     n
   <fct>                  <dbl> <int>
 1 Agelaioides badius      2003     1
 2 Agelaioides badius      2004     1
 3 Agelaioides badius      2005     1
 4 Amaurospiza moesta      2005     1
 5 Amaurospiza moesta      2014     1
 6 Ammodramus humeralis    2010     1
 7 Ammodramus humeralis    2011     1
 8 Anabacerthia amaurotis  2001     1
 9 Anabacerthia amaurotis  2004     1
10 Anabacerthia amaurotis  2012     1
# ... with 1,855 more rows```

Comment: @Recology  Sorry, I meant `df1 %>% distinct(species, year) %>% count(species) %>% mutate(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all`

Comment: The reason is that when we do the `count` on both 'species', 'year', it will return only a single 1.  Instead, on the subset, it should be only for `species` count.  If there are more than one unique 'year', it will always be greater than 1

Comment: Now I have this answer: ``` df1 %>% distinct(espece, year) %>% count(espece) %>% mutate(flag = n > 1) %>% pull(flag) %>% all
[1] TRUE``` is this what we are looking for?

Comment: @Recology yes, that is the answer. sorry for the previous code.  I should have tested it